# How to underline siunitx numbers with soul?

Tags: line-breaking, siunitx, soul, percent-sign

I'm trying to write very long lines of underlined text containing percentages using [soul](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/soul/) for allowing linebreaking and [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for getting the right spacing, as I do in the rest of the document.

Unfortunately, when I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"
! 
! Invalid token '4' in numerical input.
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{unit-mode = text, output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\textit{\ul{Very very very very very very very very very very long line of text. 40\% is printed without errors.}}

\ul{\textit{Very very very very very very very very very very long line of text. 40\% is printed without errors.}}

\ul{\textit{Very very very very very very very very very very long line of text. \SI{40}{\percent} gives the error}}

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By far the easiest way is to group the entire `\SI` block in braces:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{soul}
\soulregister\SI{1}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{unit-mode = text, output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\textit{\ul{Very very very very very very very very very very long line of text. 40\% is printed without errors.}}

\ul{\textit{Very very very very very very very very very very long line of text. 40\% is printed without errors.}}

\ul{\textit{Very very very very very very very very very very long line of text. {\SI{40}{\percent}} gives the error}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using a pair of braces is indeed easier than the solution I was going to post, which was to use and `\mbox` wrapper...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does actually resolve the compile error. Do you also know how to keep the text in italics?

Comment: @Alessandro `\sisetup{detect-mode, detect-shape}` or all kind of detections: `\sisetup{detect-all}`.